# Unexpected ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED from group SpecialServiceRQ

Tags: c#, web-services, sabre

Trying to add SSRs to all passengers on a large group booking using the SpecialServiceRQ method, but getting an **ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED** response for the 50 passengers on the booking.

The [documentation](http://webservices.sabre.com/drc/servicedoc/SpecialServiceLLSRQ_v2.3.0_Design.xml) for the SERVICE node suggests that it can be repeated up to 99 in the one request.
After some experimentation then the service will return a good response with up to 47 repeats of the SERVICE node, after that the **ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED** response is given.

The request being made is

```
<SpecialServiceRQ Version="2.3.0" 
    xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
    <SpecialServiceInfo>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="02.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="03.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="04.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="05.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="06.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="07.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="08.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="09.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="10.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="11.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="12.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="13.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="14.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="15.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="16.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="17.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="18.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="19.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="20.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="21.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="22.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="23.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="24.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="25.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="26.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="27.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="28.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="29.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="30.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="31.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="32.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="33.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="34.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="35.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="36.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="37.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="38.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="39.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="40.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="41.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="42.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="43.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="44.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="45.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="46.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="47.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="48.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="49.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="50.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="AFFI">
            <PersonName NameNumber="51.01" />
            <Text>AFFIDAVIT COMPLETE</Text>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
    </SpecialServiceInfo>
</SpecialServiceRQ>
```

Comment: Sabre put 99 when the XML is <xs:element name="Service" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">. In fact most of the time there is a lower limit. Seems to be 47in your case. Best thing you can do would be to contact them.

Comment: Maybe try to send 2 requests (split your list at 47th)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this and obtained "Request exceeded maximum Host Command length". That would mean that native Sabre won't take such a long concatenation of SSRs, thus you should split your request as advised. This is a low-level service so it's basically just sending a blue-screen format behind the scenes.